# Any escaping built into Meteor?

Tags: html, handlebars.js

does Meteor offer any escaping shortcut like the backslash used in some programming languages? (BTW, I did search the docs)

```
<template name="hello">
  <h1>H1 text of &lt;template&gt; "hello"</h1>
</template>
```

For example, would there be any way to escape the <> tags in the above example?

Comment: What exactly do you want to escape at what point? You're already escaping `< >` using HTML entities. Now do you want to escape those entities again? This is probably more an HTML or template engine related rather than a meteor specific question.

Comment: Ok, then I guess it's html related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to escape the `<` so that it doesn't actually display `<` but `&lt;`, you should write `&amp;lt;`.